# Grails 2.1.1 requires 'grails clean' before every 'grails run-app' -- command line only

Tags: grails, grails-2.1

I just inherited an existing app, and the first thing I noticed is that I have to do a 'grails clean' before every 'grails run-app', or I get errors.   The people who created the project said they have several other projects with similar setups that do NOT get this error, and have been unable to track this problem down for this particular project.

Details:

From the command line, the first time I run it, I get this output:

> > grails run-app
>
> Compiling 192 source files

and it goes on to run fine.   If I then control-C out of it and run the exact same command (no changes, no anything),  I instead get:

> | Compiling 4 source files.
>   | Error Compilation error: startup failed:
>   General error during class generation: object is not an instance of
>   declaring class
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of
>   declaring class   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureAnnotation(Java5.java:242)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.setAnnotationMetaData(Java5.java:179)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.vmplugin.v5.Java5.configureClassNode(Java5.java:325)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.lazyClassInit(ClassNode.java:262)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.getInterfaces(ClassNode.java:356)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.declaresInterface(ClassNode.java:946)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.implementsInterface(ClassNode.java:926)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.isDerivedFromGroovyObject(ClassNode.java:916)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.isGroovyObject(AsmClassGenerator.java:1090)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitPropertyExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1047)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.PropertyExpression.visit(PropertyExpression.java:55)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitGStringExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1855)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.GStringExpression.visit(GStringExpression.java:50)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMapExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1444)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MapExpression.visit(MapExpression.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMapExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:1444)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MapExpression.visit(MapExpression.java:53)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.CallSiteWriter.makeCallSite(CallSiteWriter.java:301)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:187)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeCall(InvocationWriter.java:89)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.makeInvokeMethodCall(InvocationWriter.java:73)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.InvocationWriter.writeInvokeMethod(InvocationWriter.java:292)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethodCallExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:655)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.MethodCallExpression.visit(MethodCallExpression.java:75)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.evaluateEqual(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:296)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.BinaryExpressionHelper.eval(BinaryExpressionHelper.java:79)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBinaryExpression(AsmClassGenerator.java:519)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.BinaryExpression.visit(BinaryExpression.java:49)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(StatementWriter.java:599)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeExpressionStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:346)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitExpressionStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:501)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.ExpressionStatement.visit(ExpressionStatement.java:40)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.StatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(StatementWriter.java:80)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.asm.OptimizingStatementWriter.writeBlockStatement(OptimizingStatementWriter.java:155)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitBlockStatement(AsmClassGenerator.java:447)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.BlockStatement.visit(BlockStatement.java:69)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClassCodeContainer(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:101)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitConstructorOrMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:112)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitStdMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:311)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitConstructorOrMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:268)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitMethod(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:123)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitMethod(AsmClassGenerator.java:388)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassNode.visitContents(ClassNode.java:1056)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.visitClass(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:50)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.AsmClassGenerator.visitClass(AsmClassGenerator.java:172)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:770)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$14.call(CompilationUnit.java:787)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToPrimaryClassNodes(CompilationUnit.java:970)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:548)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:526)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:503)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:482)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.compile(FileSystemCompiler.java:60)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.tools.FileSystemCompiler.doCompilation(FileSystemCompiler.java:216)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.compile(Groovyc.java:935)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.Grailsc.compile(Grailsc.java:79)
>     at org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovyc.execute(Groovyc.java:629)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor148.invoke(Unknown Source)    at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at groovy.util.AntBuilder.performTask(AntBuilder.java:260)  at
>   groovy.util.AntBuilder.nodeCompleted(AntBuilder.java:220)     at
>   groovy.util.BuilderSupport.doInvokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:147)    at
>   groovy.util.AntBuilder.doInvokeMethod(AntBuilder.java:170)    at
>   groovy.util.BuilderSupport.invokeMethod(BuilderSupport.java:64)   at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBuilder.invokeMethod(GantBuilder.java:99)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:45)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:120)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:263)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compile$0.callCurrent(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler.compile(GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy:234)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.compiler.GrailsProjectCompiler$compile.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:48)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6_closure7.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)    at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>     at java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)  at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy.withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy:69)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy.this$4$withCompilationErrorHandling(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:47)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2_closure6.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)    at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:287)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:938)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1117)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1073)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>     at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)  at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:145)
>     at
>   _GrailsCompile_groovy$_run_closure2.doCall(_GrailsCompile_groovy:46)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:428)    at
>   sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor106.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:39)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:54)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16_closure18.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)    at
>   java_util_concurrent_Callable$call.call(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy:90)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding.this$4$withTargetEvent(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy:185)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantBinding$_initializeGantBinding_closure5_closure16.doCall(GantBinding.groovy)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:415)    at
>   groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:409)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1071)   at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokePropertyOrMissing(MetaClassImpl.java:1117)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1073)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:721)    at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>     at groovy.lang.Script.invokeMethod(Script.java:78)  at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   groovy.lang.DelegatingMetaClass.invokeMethod(DelegatingMetaClass.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.gant.GantMetaClass.invokeMethod(GantMetaClass.java:168)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.invokeMethod(GroovyObjectSupport.java:44)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethodOnGroovyObject(MetaClassImpl.java:1136)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1030)
>     at
>   groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
>     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:901)   at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:137)
>     at
>   _GrailsPackage_groovy$_run_closure2_closure9.doCall(_GrailsPackage_groovy:45)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:231)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
>     at

Curiously, from within IntelliJ, if I do run-app from the menu after a (command line) grails clean, I get the same 'compiling 192 source files' message and it works, the second time I get 'compiling 4 source files', and it still works.

I've googled to no avail.   I'm not even sure how to begin solving this.   Can anyone point me down the path to a solution for this?  What do I even look at?  How can it work in the IDE and not the command line when, apparently, the same compile takes place?  What does the error mean?

Comment: You don't need to show the whole long stack but you have cut it off short enough that it isn't clear what the problem is.  Can you show just enough of the stack to get to a frame that includes your code?

Comment: I had looked through the error, and didn't see any reference to anything that looked related to the project, which is why I truncated it.    I have edited the post to show as much of the error as this site will let me.  If you think more would be helpful, I can try to find a way to post it.  Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try running without reloading (which I think was `grails -noreloading run-app`) - does that address it?

If it does, we can dig a little deeper: it might be just the slcache that is being populated incorrectly, which can happen if using an up to date JDK with an older spring loaded. Between restarts (just using regular `grails run-app`) delete the .slcache - `rm -rf ~/grails/2.1.3/.slcache` rather than a grails clean. Does that make a difference?

I would then grab a more recent spring loaded (e.g. 1.2.0.RELEASE.jar from here in central:  http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/springloaded/1.2.0.RELEASE/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar

Find the spring loaded jar in your grails 2.1.3 installation. Rename it (to back it up). Then copy the 1.2.0 jar into that folder and rename it to match the original spring loaded jar. I found mine here:

`grails-2.1.3/lib/org.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.1.1.jar`

So I'd copy `springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar` into that folder and rename it to `springloaded-core-1.1.1.jar`

One more `grails clean` and then try run-app again. Any better?

Comment: That is some great sleuthing there.

The -noreloading works, I can run as many times as I wanted.

Deleting .slcache made no difference at all.

Renaming springloaded-core and putting in a more recent version worked.

So if I may impose on you for a few more questions: 

Can you give me a 50 cent explanation of your voodoo magic, and what all that means?

And why did it work before in IntelliJ but not the command line? Shouldn't they both be using the same Grails directory (from what I can tell they are).

Comment: Couple of factors in the mix. If you are using different JDK levels in different setups, it can change things. Also if you run grails 'directly' without going through the launching script (which could be the IntelliJ case) it possibly wouldn't be turning on the spring loaded caching - which is what leads to this problem. The basic problem is the cache is getting a bad entry created on the first start which is reused on the second start. Something is cached that never should have been. More recent springloadeds don't cache this thing.

Comment: Got it, thanks again for your help.  I'd up vote you but apparently I haven't been active enough to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely a nasty problem. During development it is natural that once in a while a clean might be required.

However, what you describe sounds constantly reproducible and you should definitely find the cause. Here is a strategy how I would tackle the issue. I assume you have everything under version control.

1. create a brand-new project with the same name, same grails version.
2. Delete all files from your project and copy files from (1) into you project. Now you have a clean project and a huge diff.
3. Start by reverting (complete or line by line) your BuildConfig.groovy. It is definitely a big possibility that the cause is somewhere here.
4. Next I would revert Config.groovy / Datasource.groovy / Bootstrap.
5. Now if you still could not isolate the cause it must be your code. Keep reverting until you finally find the reason. Revert resources.groovy on the way, as soon as you have the classes available.